# Drupal 8 block cacheing

Tags: caching

I have written a block, displayed on the right sidebar of my drupal 8 site. It reads the database, and shows today's reports. But the block's output is aggressively cached, so that it never shows the up-to-date details. The block's code is being called, and returns the correct data, but this is ignored. (Pages created by controller classes do similar work, but are not cached. What's the difference?).

After reading many help pages, I'm frustrated; I can't get the block to show up-to-date details. The solution seems to involve setting '#cache' on the render array returned, but I can't see how.

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do exactly.  I have a block that is dependent on the user thats logged in, and it may also be changed from time to time based on some other code being run.

In this example

```
'#cache'=>[
        'contexts'=> [
            'user',
            'route',
        ],
        'tags' => [
          'Block:smn',
        ],
      ],
```

It gives it context for which to cache and the tag allows me to invalidate the cache for just this block if I run some other code that will affect what is rendered

in this example if some entity is deleted i use hook_entity_delete

```
function foo_entity_delete($entity){
    $cache = \Drupal::service('cache_tags.invalidator')->invalidateTags(array('Block:smn'));

}
```

and my block will be removed from cache and the next time I visit the page it will be rendered with new information.

for more info on tags, and contexts you can cache with:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/cache/8.2.x

Comment: Thanks. What I want to do is to show all my users the latest info, not yesyerday's... I naively thought that this was the default position for 100% of web pages...    In the database update code in the controller class I put \Drupal::service('cache_tags.invalidator')->invalidateTags(array('Block:sitereport'));   In the blcck code I returned:       '#title' => $this->t("Today's flying"),
      '#cache' => ['tags' => [ 'Block:sitereport' ] ],
   '#markup' => $this->t($content)   It still displays yyesterday's data. The controller class page is fine....,

Comment: OK, I added the context keys that you supplied, and it now works. Thank Dog for that. Thanks very much. Now to understand why...